# issue with password check

Tags: php, mysql

im having a strange issue when im trying to submit a form.
This is to change a user password. the problem i have is that when i check with the php the password to see length, type, etc if the user sets the new password only with letters it gives me the message "password must be at least 6 characters long" and with numbers it is not happening. And if i change the check to $npass > 6 its the oposite, it takes letters and not numbers.
Really strange. Its like its not taking the letters. Any ideas?

This is the code:

```
 <input type="password" name="pass">
 <input type="password" name="npass">
 <input type="password" name="npass2">
```

this is the check php

```
$pass = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['pass']);
$pass = md5($pass);
$npass = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['npass']);
$npass2 = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['npass2']);


if(empty($pass))
{
die(msg(0,"Type in your current password"));
}


elseif($pass != $current)
{
die(msg(0,"<div>Your current password is incorrect</div>"));
}

elseif(empty($npass))
{
die(msg(0,"<div>Type new password</div>"));
}

elseif($npass < 6)
{
die(msg(0,"<div>Password must be at least 6 characters long</div>"));
}

elseif(empty($npass2))
{
die(msg(0,"<div>Please repeat your new password</div>"));
}

elseif($npass != $npass2)
{
die(msg(0,"<div>Passwords doesnt match</div>"));
}
```

Comment: This is not strange but a mistake. Why have you replace user's input before performing check? See [PHP: preg_replace - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Please dont use `md5` for storing passwords. Its strongly recommended to use `password_hash`

Comment: You commit 2 kinds of mistakes in your script: 1) your calls to preg_replace() actually remove any occurence of a letter or number from the input string; and 2) ($npass < 6) actually tests if $npass, converted to an integer, is inferior to 6; to test the length of the string, you should rather test whether (strlen($npass) < 6). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below function

```
function checkPasswordStrength($password)
{
            if(!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $password))
                return false;  // for capital letter

            elseif(!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $password))
                return false;  // for number

            elseif(!preg_match("/[a-z]/", $password) )
                return false; // for small letter

            elseif(!preg_match("/[`!%$&^*()@#]+/", $password))
                return false; // for special character

            elseif(strlen($password) < 8)
                return false; // for password length
            else
                return true;
}
```